# Incorrect result in showing the total number of records of view in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

**Requirement:**
There are 3 data frames df1,df2, and df4 containing some records and we have created a temp view out of the dataframes named "aaa","bbb" and "ccc" respectively.
There is another dataframe df3 containing a column table_name having 3 values "aaa","bbb" and "ccc".We have created a temp view of df3 as "tables".
We have to create another dataframe containing 2 columns, 1st containing temp view names and the second containing a number of records of the corresponding view.

I have tried the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object SampleDemo1 {
  val spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("SampleDemo1").getOrCreate()
  val sc=spark.sparkContext
  import spark.implicits._
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val l1=List((1,"ABC",50),(2,"PQR",70))
    val l2=List((3,"MNO",75),(4,"XYZ",100))
    val l4=List((3,"MNO",75),(4,"XYZ",100),(4,"XYZ",100))
    val df1=l1.toDF("id","name","age")
    val df2=l2.toDF("id","name","age")
    val df4=l4.toDF("id","name","age")
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("aaa")
    df2.createOrReplaceTempView("bbb")
    df4.createOrReplaceTempView("ccc")

    val l3=List(("aaa"),("bbb"),("ccc"))
    val df3=l3.toDF("table_name")
    df3.createOrReplaceTempView("tables")
    //spark.sql("select * from tables").show
    val dfresult=spark.sql("""select table_name,(select count(1) from (select table_name from tables)) as number_of_records from tables""")
    dfresult.show
  }
}
```

**output:**

> ```
> +----------+-----------------+
> |table_name|number_of_records|
> +----------+-----------------+
> |       aaa|                3|
> |       bbb|                3|
> |       ccc|                3|
> +----------+-----------------+
> ```

**Expected Output:**

> ```
> +----------+-----------------+
> |table_name|number_of_records|
> +----------+-----------------+
> |       aaa|                2|
> |       bbb|                2|
> |       ccc|                3|
> +----------+-----------------+
> ```

**Issue:
The issue in the code is, as the df1 and df2 contain a total of 2 records but the solution is showing as a number of records as 3. While the df4 contains the 3 records and it is showing correctly.**

Could anyone please guide me in solving the issue in the correct manner?

Comment: Hi and welcome, perhaps you can add an example of the expected output and why it is expected instead of the current result.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to count the number of records in each view, it is recommended to use `union all`.

```
    val dfresult=spark.sql("""
        select 'aaa' as table_name,count(*) as number_of_records  from aaa
        union all
        select 'bbb' as table_name,count(*) as number_of_records  from bbb
        union all
        select 'ccc' as table_name,count(*) as number_of_records  from ccc
    """)
```